# Is it possible to inject javascript into a twitter feed to customize it's colors, font, etc.?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

Is it possible to create a safari extension to inject javascript that will alter twitter feed color, font, etc., once it's loaded on screen, or has twitter somehow disabled this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. You can use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (for Firefox) or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) (for Google Chrome) to create [userscripts](https://greasyfork.org/en) which are Javascript scripts that are executed on the pages that you specify.

- Here's a similar userscript I wrote for facebook: [customizefb](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/8290-customizefb)
- Here's one I wrote for StackOverflow: [Who downvoted me?!](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/18778-who-downvoted-me)
- And here [are a bunch other people have already written for twitter](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/search?q=twitter).

You can always run custom Javascript directly from the browser console too if you don't want to install the userscript plugin.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Had another question I was hoping you could answer. I'm trying to make a very simpl Safari extension at the moment. If I run:

var myNodelist = document.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink");

myNodelist[0].style.backgroundColor = "red"',

The first question text on stackoverflow.com has its text color changed to red. If I extract the class name for some tweet text in twitter and run it again, nothing happens. Do you know why this script works for some sites and not others?

Comment: I'd be happy to help you with that but let's please follow SO protocol. First, if my answer helped you please upvote and/or click the ckeckmark to accept the answer. Then, please open a new question rather than asking in the comments. Once you open a new question, if you'd like, you can come back here and post a link to the new question and I'll be happy to check it out. @Kyle

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623099/creating-a-simple-twitter-safari-extension-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Twitter cannot "somehow disable" that; if you inject Javascript/CSS into a page via an extension you can do whatever you want.