# Creating a simple Twitter Safari extension using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

How would one go about creating a simple Twitter Safari extension using Javascript? Ideally, I would like to find tweet post titles and change their text color as a user scrolls down the screen. I know the twitter feed loads dynamically, so I suppose the script would have to execute each time new tweets are loaded for the user.

I'm very new to JavaScript, but executing something like:

```
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink");
myNodelist[0].style.backgroundColor = "red"
```

will change link colors on, for example, stackoverflow.com but not on Twitter.

So my questions would be, how does one grab tweet text dynamically as they're loaded, and how does one alter its appearance? Thanks!

Comment: I hope that answered your question. If you got satisfactory answers from your other questions you should mark a selected answer. You get two points from each answer you accept. You have enough rep to upvote now too ;). good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inspector in the Firefox or Chrome [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Use_the_Inspector_from_the_Web_Console) to view the classes and id's of a given element.

Twitter tweets have a classname of `tweet`, so for example, the following would make all the tweet's backgrounds red and log the tweet text to the console..

```
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByClassName("tweet");
for(var i=0; i<myNodelist.length; i++){
  // change the background to red
  myNodelist[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"

  // get the actual tweet text
  var tweet = myNodelist[i].getElementsByClassName('TweetTextSize')[0].textContent.trim();
  console.log(tweet);
}
```